# svg text transform-rotate changes x and y position of text tag

Tags: html, css, svg

When I apply `transform="rotate(-10.867784481465419)"` to my `svg-text` tag, it changes its `x` and `y` position visually.

**with transform="rotate(0)"**

```html
<html>
<body>

<svg height="300" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="175" transform="rotate(0)" fill="red">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**with transform="rotate(-10.867784481465419)"**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="330" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="175" fill="red" transform="rotate(-10.867784481465419)">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

How can I only change rotation not x, y positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are rotating about the origin but the text is not at the origin. Imagine you have a clock where centre of the clock face is the origin and the minute hand is half past the hour ending at 0,175. 10 minutes ago the second hand was to the right and slightly above where it is now, same as your situation.

If you want to rotate about the start point of the text, translate it into position and then rotate it. That way the text is at the local origin when you rotate it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="330" width="200">
  <text fill="red" transform="translate(0, 175) rotate(-10.867784481465419)">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

Any rotations will happen around the centre of rotation. That's at (0, 0) - the top left of the SVG.

If you want the text to rotate around a different point in the SVG, then you have to specify a different origin. There are a couple of way to do that, but the simplest way is to use the other version of `rotate()` which takes an `x` and `y` position to rotate around.

```
rotate(angle, x, y)
```

or in your specific case:

```
rotate(-10.86, 0, 175)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="330" width="200">
  <text x="0" y="175" fill="red" transform="rotate(-10.86, 0, 175)">I love SVG!</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```